# Orbifold line bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

I was going through the paper - http://repository.ias.ac.in/3652/1/427.pdf, and I got this question. Let $Y$ be a connected smooth projective variety of dimension $n$ over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $G$ be a finite group acting faithfully on $Y$.

An orbifold line bundle on $Y$ is a line bundle $L$ on $Y$ together with a lift of action of $G$, which means that $G$ acts on the total space of $L$, and for any g ∈ $G$, the action of $g$ on $L$ is an isomorphism between $L$ and $\rho(g^{ −1} )^∗ L$.

But he further remarks that,  A line bundle $L$ with the property that for any $g\in G$, the bundle $L$ is isomorphic to $\rho(g^{-1})^∗L$, need not have an orbifold structure. I am confused by this. I am trying to think of line bundles which satisfy this isomorphism property, but are not orbifold bundles.

Is this the right example? Consider the quotient $X=Y/G$, assume that it is non-singular. Let $D\subset X$ be the ramification divisor (say it is smooth). Consider $D'\subset Y$ the reduced pull back of $D$. Note that $p:D'\rightarrow D$ is a finite flat morphism, and $G$ acts on $D'$. The line bundle $O_Y(D')|_{D'}$ on $D'$ is isomorphic to $g^*O_Y(D')|_{D'}$, for all $g$. But is it an orbifold line bundle on $D'$?

I think not. For, given an orbifold line bundle $L$ on $D'$, consider the push forward $p_*L$ to $D$. Then we can define the subsheaf of $G$-invariants $(p_*L)^G$ as the image of the averaging operator on $p_*L$. The same paper says that $(p_*L)^G$ is a sub-line bundle of $p_*L$, and that $p^*(p_*L)^G\subset L$.

If $L=O_Y(D')|_{D'}$, then I cannot think of any line bundle $M$ on $D$ such that $p^*M\subset L$. Thus, $(p_*L)^G=0$, and that is clearly not a line bundle.

Does any of this make sense? Or am I completely wrong. Forgive me if I am completely off, this is a new area for me, and I need to apply it in my work. I am trying work out some examples to understand.

Comment: Take $X=\mathbb{P}^1$, $L=\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1)$, $G$ finite $\subset \mathrm{PGL}(2)$.   
Then $g^*L\cong L$ for any  $g\in G$, but saying that $L$ has a "orbifold structure" in your sense (that is, a linear action of $G$) is equivalent to say that $G$ lifts to $\mathrm{GL}(2)$, which is not always the case: a simple example is
 $G=\mathbb{Z}/2\times \mathbb{Z}/2$ acting by the involutions $z\mapsto -z$ and  $z\mapsto 1/z$.

Comment: Your example does not work: if $G=\mathbb{Z}/2$, $p:D'\rightarrow D$ is the identity, so the action is trivially linearizable.

Comment: @abx, you are right. I am confused now though. If $L$ is the line bundle $L=O_Y(D')|_{D'}$, what is $(p_*L)^G$? Is it not zero.

Comment: A line bundle does not split. Let me stop this discussion, please consider asking on MSE.

Comment: In the paper that you link to, any $L$ isomorphic to $\rho(g^{-1})^*L$ for all $g$ is assigned a class in $H^2(G;{\mathbb C}^*)$ which is the obstruction to the existence of an orbifold bundle structure.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე, you are correct. I was trying to work some specific example.  I wanted to see if I can use the criterion in the paper which mentions, if $L$ is a orbifold line bundle on $Y$, then $(p_*L)^G$ is a line bundle as well.